# Remove history entry in Jquery Address

Tags: jquery

When for example a customer adds an item to the cart I set the address through  [Jquery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) to `/cart/23432 (productid)`. After the item has been added to the cart and the cart details have been shown, i want to change the url to `/cart/`. In that way when the customer refreshes the page, the product is not added again. However, now there will be two history entries

```
 1. /cart/23432
 2. /cart/
```

When i change the address to `/cart/`, how do i delete the previous entry `(/cart/23432)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach

```
        $.address.history(false);
        $.address.value(yoururl);
        $.address.history(true);
```

This will replace the last history entry with the new url